# Regular expression for selecting single spaced phrases but not whitespace

Tags: regex, perl

I need a rather complicated regular expression that will select words with one space between them and that can include the '-' symbol in them, it should not however select continuous whitespace.

```
'KENEDY JOHN G JR E'                  'example'                 'D-54'
```

I have tried the following regular expression:

```
\'([\s\w-]+)\'
```

but it selects continuous whitespace which I don't want it to do.

I want the expression to select

```
'KENEDY JOHN G JR E'
'example'
'D-54'
```

Comment: "rather complicated"? [I think not](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/perl-regex-that-matches-prime-numbers/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps,

```
\'([\w-]+(?:\s[\w-]+)*)\'
```

?

**EDIT**

If leading/trailing dashes (on the word boundaries) are not allowed, this should read:

```
/\'(\w+(?:[\s-]\w+)*)\'/
```

Answer (score 1):

An expression like this should do it:

```
'[\w-]+(?:\s[\w-]+)*'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
my $data = "'KENEDY JOHN G JR E'                  'example'                 'D-54'";

# Sets of
#     one or more word characters or dash
#     followed by an optional space
# enclosed in single quotes
#
# The outermost ()s are optional. There just
# so i can print the match easily as $1.
while ($data =~ /(\'([\w-]+\s?)+\')/g)
{
    print $1, "\n";
}
```

outputs

```
'KENEDY JOHN G JR E'
'example'
'D-54'
```

Comment: Ooops! Sorry, you wanted a rather complicated regexp. This one may be too simple for you! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this applies to you, since you asked for a regex specifically. However, if you want strings separated by two or more whitespace or dashes, you can use [`split`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html)

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use v5.10;

my $str = q('KENEDY JOHN G JR E'               'example'              'D-54');
my @match = split /\s{2,}/, $str;
say for @match;
```

A regex with similar functionality would be

```
my @match = $str =~ /(.*?)(?:\s{2,}|$)/g;
```

Note that you'll need the edge case of finding end of line `$`.

The benefit of using `split` or the wildcard `.` is that you rely on whitespace to define your fields, not the content of the fields themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Your code actually works as is.

```
use feature qw( say );
$_ = "'KENEDY JOHN G JR E'         'example'         'D-54'";
say for /\'([\s\w-]+)\'/g;
```

output:

```
KENEDY JOHN G JR E
example
D-54
```

(Move the parens if you want the quotes too.)

I would simply use

```
my @data = /'([^']*)'/g;
```

If you have any validation to do, do it afterwards.